# How to change default gripper Style CToolbar?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I am using MFC c++. I using CToolBar i try to changing the default Gripper Style:

```
if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
        !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }
```

I want to change this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Try `SetWindowTheme(m_wndToolBar.m_hWnd,L"",L"")`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thank you its work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally its work.
Thanks to  Barmak Shemirani.

```
Method 1: (docking enable)

   SetWindowTheme(m_wndToolBar.m_hWnd,L"",L"")


Method 2: (docking not working)

    CReBarCtrl& rbc = m_wndReBar.GetReBarCtrl();
        REBARBANDINFO rbbi;
        rbbi.cbSize = sizeof(rbbi);
        rbbi.fMask = RBBIM_STYLE;
        int nCount = rbc.GetBandCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
        {
            rbc.GetBandInfo(i, &rbbi);
            rbbi.fStyle |= RBBS_NOGRIPPER;
            rbbi.fStyle &= ~RBBS_GRIPPERALWAYS;
            rbc.SetBandInfo(i, &rbbi);
        }
```